# How does this process to strip a list of files works with %% and no variable name?

Tags: bash, shell

This works but I don't understand it. I can't find any information on what `${*%%` means. The information I found says it needs to be `${varname%%`.

Also, what exactly is `$()` used for? Does it make it process the function one time for each line in the file list?

```
strip_mod_c() {
    # What is "*" in the variable name spot?
    result="${*%%*.mod.c}"
    echo "$result"
}
SOURCES_ALL=`find $BASEDIR -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.c"`
# Also, why is this done inside $( ) ?
SOURCES_ALL=$( strip_mod_c $SOURCES_ALL )
```

Comment: Note that this fragment of code accumulates bad practices, with using deprecated back-tick command expansion and splitting strings on the `IFS` delimiters.

Comment: I would rather recommend `find .... -not -name '*.mod.c' -and '(' -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' ')'`

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find any information on what `${*%%` means when the information I found says it needs to be `${varname%%`.

It *is* `${varname%%`, where `varname` is `*`.

[The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) has this to say about it:

> `${parameter%word}`
>  `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The `word` is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern
> matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of `parameter`, then
> the result of the expansion is the value of `parameter` with the
> shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching
> pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. **If `parameter` is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
> pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in
> turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.**

You also asked,

> Also, what exactly is `$()` used for?

`$()` delimits a command substitution.  The shell code within is executed, and its standard output captured and substituted in place of the `$(...)`.  This is pretty much the same as `...`, but there are some differences in how quoting is handled within.

> Does it make it process the function one time for each line in the file list?

No.  See above.  Overall, the script fragment runs `find` and captures the result in variable `SOURCES_ALL`.  Then it runs the result (all at once, split on whitespace) through function `strip_mod_c`, captures the result, and assigns it back to `SOURCES_ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

`${*}` is the variable `$*`, which is the script or function arguments expanded as a single string. Per the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> ###### 3.4.2 Special Parameters
>
> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> - `($*)` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and filename expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c…"`, where *c* is the first character of the value of the `IFS` variable. If `IFS` is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If `IFS` is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

`$()` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). It captures the output of a command as a string. `VAR=$(cmd)` assigns the output of `cmd` to `$VAR`.